# WPF: ListView inside of Scrollviewer; Layout question

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, layout, scrollviewer

i do have a question about layouting with a listview inside of a scrollviewer. Once a listview is inside a scrollviewer it does use it's maximum size and doesn't scroll itself cause the scrollviewer offers unlimited amount of space to the controls inside of it.
The problem is, that controls that are below a long list are only visible if the user scrolls down and I want to make the listview only use the space that is necessary and use a scrollbar itself. Pictures do tell more information than words (links for pictures also do tell much as my reputation isn't at 10 yet.. Edit2: well i can use only one link so i copied all pictures onto one). 
If the lists isn't long everything is okay:

Picture 1 : [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dDEC.jpg]

Now if the list is longer the controls below move down into the invisible land:

Picture 2 : see link from picture 1

What I do want to happen now is this:

Picture 3 : see link from picture 1

That itself isn't really a problem cause we could put everything in a dockpanal and do dock the controls below to Dock.Below and Top to Top and let the listview fill the center with "lastchildfill". Now for the real problem. What if the window gets smaller? Then at first the listview disappears and then also everything else without having a scrollbar to scroll to the controls on the bottom.

Picture 4 : see link from picture 1

The ideal **solution** i am searching for is to have scrollbars on the window (or a root scrollviewer) which would enable us to scroll to every section of the window like this and just have the outer scrollbars to be visible once everything is a minimum size.

Picture 5 : see link from picture 1

ANY IDEAS? too many pictures? here's a little bit of xaml for everyone to try making it work (it's just a fast example windows...)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest1.ScrollTestWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
Title="ScrollTestWindow" Height="400" Width="700">
    <ScrollViewer >
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <TextBlock Text="Example controls above listview" Background="LightGray" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                <TextBlock Text="Example controls below listview" Background="LightGray" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <ListView FontSize="30">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="190" Header="Date" />
                        <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Day Of Week"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DayOfWeek}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Year" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
                <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
            </ListView>
        </DockPanel>

    </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. So I had the same problem, but have now managed to solve it!

My project looks a little different than yours, but I think that it should work for you to. The solution that I'm presenting also has some limitation to it. For example, it will only work if you only add one *ListView*! In your example you only have one, so that won't be a problem there. But for anyone that might want more *ListViews*, you'll have to add more functionality for deciding the sizes of the Views, and where to put them.

You will also have to have a *MinHeight* set for the *ListView.*

My solution is to create you own panel class that extends a *StackPanel*, override the *MeasureOverride* and the *ArrangeOverride* functions. And add the *ListView* into the created Panel

**CustomPanel:**

```
public class ScrollablePanel : StackPanel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        Size tmpSize = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        tmpSize.Height = (double)(this.Children[0] as UIElement).GetValue(MinHeightProperty);
        return tmpSize;
    }

    protected override System.Windows.Size ArrangeOverride(System.Windows.Size finalSize)
    {
        Size tmpSize = new Size(0, 0);

        //Width stays the same
        tmpSize.Width = finalSize.Width;
        
        //Height is changed
        tmpSize.Height = finalSize.Height;

        //This works only for one child!
        this.Children[0].SetCurrentValue(HeightProperty, tmpSize.Height);
        this.Children[0].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), tmpSize));
        
        return tmpSize;
    }
}
```

**The XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest1.ScrollTestWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest1"
Title="ScrollTestWindow" Height="400" Width="700">
    <ScrollViewer >
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <TextBlock Text="Example controls above listview" Background="LightGray" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                <TextBlock Text="Example controls below listview" Background="LightGray" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <local:ScrollablePanel>
                <ListView FontSize="30" MinHeight="80">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="190" Header="Date" />
                            <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Day Of Week"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DayOfWeek}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Year" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                    <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                    <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                    <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                    <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                    <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                    <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                    <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                    <sys:DateTime>1/1/1</sys:DateTime>
                </ListView>
            </local:ScrollablePanel>
        </DockPanel>

    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

It was a long time ago this question was asked, but I hope that this answer will help at least someone!

I also like to thank [@sisyphe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1287987/sisyphe) for all the help needed to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is really your ideal solution, but I personnally do this quite differently:

I use a simple grid, with n rows for what should be above the listvew, m rows for the stuff below and a row for the listview with height=*. So everything above and below is visible, a scroll bar appears in the list view when there is not enough room.

I have a working example of this, but with a DataGrid. It should be quite similar with a ListView.

Comment: That does match picture no.3, right?
Don't you have the same problem as in picture no.4 when your window gets really small?

Comment: Yes, set a MinHeight on the window if you want to avoid this. But, usually, this is left to the user's discretion. I don't think you can do much in such a case and I don't think many users will want to resize the window to such a small height.

Comment: i´m going to mark this as an answer even though it is kinda like "just don't let the window get that small".
Any different ideas?